# How to read parameter values in a constructor using javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I am instrument Java ThreadPoolExecutor  class as follows

```
if (className.contains("java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor")) {
            try {
                ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
                CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        classfileBuffer));
                CtConstructor constructor[] = ctClass.getConstructors();
                for (CtConstructor con : constructor) {
                    System.out.println("constructor " + con.getLongName());
                }
                byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                ctClass.detach();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Form this I am geeing constructor name as follows

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor,java.lang.Runnable)
```

I want to make a ThreadPoolExecutor using parameter of the constructor like this

```
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor)...
```

How to do like this.

Comment: Is not really clear what you want to do. Can you explain it better?

Comment: I want to get and use values of parameters of a constructor .